# How to send data via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to learn how does Ajax work and how I can send data by Ajax. I'm  getting no error and nothing is being echoed.

index.html

```html
  <input id="name" type="text" /><input id="button" type="button" value="Load" />
  <div id="feedback"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
```

page.php

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GE['name'])) {
     $name = $_GET['name'];
}
?>
```

ajax.js

```js
 $('#button').click(function(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
 $.ajax({
  url: 'page.php',
  data: 'name='+name,
  success: function(data){
   $('#feedback').html(data);
  }
    });
});
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Implement the error handler for ajax. Check jQuery documentation how.

Comment: in ajax requests - good practice will be - *error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }* so you can see where it is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an echo in your page php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GE['name'])) {
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 echo $name;
}
?>
```

also in your javascript send an object like this

```
data : { name : name}
```

should work

Comment: False, black bear, OP made typo.

Answer (score 0):

data : { name : 'John'}

you can check the success method is invoked or not invoked.
Also you need to echo something from php.

echo $name

Comment: I had echoed it before  I forgot to paste it in the code. I edited it again but it's still not working. I’ve already changed data to data {name, name} but that makes no difference... I think I will try with the error handling.

Comment: delete ' this things and try again :)
Do you have an js error on console?

Comment: I've already deleted the single quotation but nothing is being displayed. There is no error in the console

Comment: Can you check the request from network?
You can see the ajax request from browser developer tool

Comment: firebug->Net->all->Params-> name Alex 1 request size 0B.